# How to conduct research project using R programming language

Tags: projects, social-science, project-design

I am a student of Energy policy and International relations, I have earned a certificate in R basics with the purpose of conducting research/analysis in formulating the policies for the energy transition to renewables and have found the R language very interesting. Can you guide me on what next logical steps I take to give a professional edge to my gained knowledge?

I have heard from everyone that one should build or work on a project to showcase it on resume, now my question is from where I can get the genuine data/packages related to Social Science and renewables energies to build my own research question/project. And after building a project how and where to show it on my resume.

Comment: A bit of advice. Lots and lots of people are proficient with R, many of whom understand what they are doing. It’s simply a tool. The way to distinguish yourself, as it seems you’re asking about, is to understand your field and to be able to formulate studies, or at least assist in the process, that lend themselves to statistical analysis. When you’ve found and successfully performed a project you’re proud of, put it at the top of the Recent Projects section of your CV.

Comment: @A rural reader that would make for a good answer.

Comment: Why do you want to use R in particular?  What advantages does it give you over other languages like Python, for example?

Answer (score 11):

You have it backwards. *First* you need a research question that has the potential to improve the knowledge in your field, *then* you think about the corresponding hypotheses, and only *in the end* you worry about the data and methods needed to test them. Practically speaking, you should look for an advisor who knows the field well and can suggest some reading to explore interesting research avenues at the cutting edge. On your own, you'll likely get lost and side-tracked in the thicket of the literature.